# install pytorch with cuda support in pycharm

Tags: pytorch, pycharm, conda

i am trying to install pytorch with cuda support on pycharm and i am having some problems.
i am using conda

`(cudatest) PS C:\Users\MSI\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2> conda install cudatoolkit -c anaconda Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done`

`(cudatest) PS C:\Users\MSI\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2> conda install pytorch-cuda=12.1 -c pytorch -c nvidia -y

(cudatest) PS C:\Users\MSI\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2> conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio -c pytorch -c nvidia -y  `

`import torch

print(torch.cuda.is_available())

C:\Users\MSI\anaconda3\python.exe C:\Users\MSI\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\test.py
False

Process finished with exit code 0`

Comment: Ensure that CUDA Toolkit is installed on your system and verify the CUDA version installed is compatible with your gpu (nvidia driver version).